# Please help name plant

Tags: identification

On photo there is a plant I've got. Please help me identify what it is.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be Syngonium podophyllum and it hasn't enough room for its roots. Needs a bigger pot with more potting compost in it - it should look like this:

https://www.flickr.com/photos/rdjnapolitano/5986290754

Needs average warmth, minimum 15 Deg C in winter, and a well lit (by daylight) but sunless spot. Compost should not be allowed to dry out completely, but take care not to overwater - drainage holes in the bottom of the pot and emptying out any outer container after 30 minutes are important. Reduce watering in winter, but don't allow to dry out completely, mist leaves regularly, particularly in winter, assuming you have central heating.